# C++ function signature hint in Emacs?

Tags: c++, emacs

Can we let emacs display the function signatures and overloading candidates when typing a function name and the parameter list? This will be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with CEDET (built in) together with
[function-args](https://github.com/abo-abo/function-args):

[image: function-args]

Some features:

1. `fa-show` shows function arguments inline, allowing to switch between overloads.
2. `fa-jump` jumps to an overloaded candidate (when there are many).
3. `moo-complete` gives better completion sometimes, and uses `helm` which is an advantage for speed.
4. `moo-propose-virtual` uses `helm` to instantly fill in a
   virtual function signature in an overloaded class.
5. `moo-propose-override` does so for any parent function (not just virtual).